# What is the meaning of Mark 10:29-30?

Tags: mark

Jesus says that anyone who leaves everything and everyone behind to follow Him will be rewarded:

> Mark 10:29-30: "Jesus said, 'Truly I say to you, there is no one who has left house or brothers or sisters or mother or father or children or farms, for My sake and for the gospel’s sake, <sup>30</sup>but that he will receive a hundred times as much now in the present age, houses and brothers and sisters and mothers and children and farms, along with persecutions; and in the age to come, eternal life.'"

What does this mean?

Comment: Please correct your non-existent reference and quote the verse to which you refer.

Comment: @Donice Hi and welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**What is the meaning of Mark 10:29-30?**

Jesus says that anyone who leaves everything and everyone behind to follow Him will be rewarded:

Correct, Jesus gave the following assurance he/she will one hundredfold in the present age and in the age to come eternal life. [Read verse 30 below]

Jesus and the Rich Young Ruler

Mark 10:17-22 NASB

> 17 As He was setting out on a journey, a man ran up to Him and knelt
> before Him, and asked Him, “Good Teacher, what shall I do so that I
> may inherit eternal life?” 18 But Jesus said to him, “Why do you call
> Me good? No one is good except God alone. 19 You know the
> commandments: ‘Do not murder, Do not commit adultery, Do not steal, Do
> not give false testimony, Do not defraud, Honor your father and
> mother.’” 20 And he said to Him, “Teacher, I have kept all these
> things from my youth.” 21 Looking at him, Jesus showed love to him and
> said to him, “One thing you lack: go and sell all you possess and give
> to the poor, and you will have treasure in heaven; and come, follow
> Me.” 22 But he [i]was deeply dismayed by [j]these words, and he went
> away grieving; for he was one who owned much property.

Having God's favor and his Son's is worth more than anything else. Neither our friends nor our relatives can give us unfailing help, flawless guidance and everlasting life. But  God makes these things available to us through his Son. We also gain brothers, sisters, mothers, and children in a spiritual sense.

**Jesus Christ gave this assurance:**

Mark 10:28-30 NASB

> 28 Peter began to say to Him, “Behold, we have left everything and
> have followed You.” 29 Jesus said, “Truly I say to you, there is no
> one who has left house or brothers or sisters or mother or father or
> children or farms, for My sake and for the gospel’s sake, **30 [l]but
> that he will receive a hundred times as much now in [m]the present
> age, houses and brothers and sisters and mothers and children and
> farms, along with persecutions; and in the age to come, eternal life**.

Yes, wherever his disciples go, they can enjoy a brotherhood with fellow worshippers that is closer and more precious than that enjoyed with natural family members. Sadly, it seems that the rich young ruler is going to lose out on that blessing as well as the reward of life in God’s heavenly Kingdom.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we are not yet born in Holy Spirit (John 3:5) with a heavenly birth but are only born as natural men by natural birth, we are confined to a limited love of our kin, who are everything to us. It is good for the time being, even divine, for  it is from God that we have in our hearts intense love towards parents, siblings, sons and daughters, dear relatives or romantic lovers. However, this can become our obstacle also, for "man's enemy will be members of his household" (Matthew 10:36).

But how that, which is divine can become an enemy? Because the family members can block our birth and progress in Spirit. For instance, you have a romantic infatuation with a woman whose beauty is like that of Hellen of Troy, and whose embrace feels like a paradise; but you then come to a knowledge that she is not a Christian, neither wants to be a one, and does not see life as a service of God and growth in Christ, as you do, but just a *dolce vita* of earthly pleasures and comforts. It is a temptation that you sell out the Lord for the romantic infatuation and thus exchange eternal for the temporal; Or, you love your child so much and so wrongly, that you mercilessly sink businesses of other men depriving their children of sustenance; or your father is a politician and asks you to abandon expressing your Christian views on, say abortion or homosexuality, for it can harm his electoral campaign, and you pusillanimously comply; etc. In short, our closest persons whom we love the most can become the greatest temptations for us that we may betray the Lord for their sake.

However, if we overcome this temptation, are born in the Lord's Spirit, enter through the fire of the Spirit burning in us in a good and noble conflict even with our kin, just as the Lord wishes this fire of Spirit to be kindled in us (Luke 12:49) and even urges through His apostle not to quench it in our hearts and lives (1 Thes. 5:19), then we shall become friends of all those who love the Lord and kin to them with the kinship of Spirit.

But, eventually, we shall not lose even our natural kins, our natural parents, or siblings, or even romantic love, for if we die for sin and are born in Spirit, the Lord will grant us souls of even our kins, whom we shall continue loving albeit in a more sublime, spiritual way. As Paul, being born in Spirit, and through it having become friend of all nations, for Spirit has not preference for particular nations, prays for his kin Jews most ardently, and is confident that his prayers will help Jewish nation eschatologically (cf. Romans 11:26). Thus, we shall obtain entire world of Lord's followers, and be persecuted by lovers of the world for that reason ( for loving of this world is hatred towards God (1 John 2:15)), among them by our family members even, but through our endurance and care for them in Christ, we have a chance to re-obtain them in Him.

Answer (score 0):

The Greek word used for “hundredfold” in Matthew 19:29, here, and Luke 8:8 is “HEKATONTAPLASION.” Its literal meaning is “a hundred times” (Strong’s Concordance). Jesus’ use of the word “verily” (Mark 10:29) introduces a statement of solemn assurance that “every one” (Matthew 19:29) who voluntarily forsakes home, relatives, or property for the sake of Him and the Gospel will receive a hundred times more in this life and in the world to come, eternal life.

This scripture has been misapplied by many to justify covetousness. That certainly was not the intent of Jesus, as can be seen by His ministry to this rich young ruler. Our motives should never be selfish. However, regardless of anyone’s abuse of this scripture, Jesus did promise a hundredfold return “in this present time” (Luke 18:30), meaning here on earth (Matthew 6:19).

Comment: Dave Mark 10:30 NASB.  But that he will receive a hundred times as much now in [m]the present age, houses and brothers and sisters and mothers and children and farms, along with persecutions; and in the age to come, eternal life.

Comment: @OzzieOzzie Never before noticed that the hundred times factor was in this present time, distinct from the age to come.

Answer (score 0):

Let me highlight some of the words that some Christians may overlook in
Mark 10:29-30:

> Jesus said, 'Truly I say to you, there is no one who has left house or brothers or sisters or mother or father or children or farms, for **My** sake and for the **gospel’s** sake,

The endeavor is for Jesus and His Good News, not for a Christian and his version of the Good News.

> 30but that he will receive a hundred times as much now in the present age, houses and brothers and sisters and mothers and children and farms, along with **persecutions**; and in the age to come, eternal life.'

Expect persecutions if you are doing it right.

There were plenty of concrete applications in the NT. Look at the lives of Paul, Peter, James, John, etc. They are models for any Christians today who wish to follow their lifestyle of living for Jesus and His Good News.

Comment: Tony Chan: Correct, Paul and the others you mentioned are models to follow; Where can you find such a model today.  Few find the narrow gate to life-- Matthew 7:13-14

Answer (score 0):

It's plain to me, when observing the application of this promise in the lives of the Apostles who left everything for Christ, that this meant the value of everything we voluntarily surrender as the result of seeking to remain faithful to Christ and His Cause, will be nothing compared to the value of a closer more intimate relationship with God and His people, a deeper faith, a stronger hope, a greater joy and lasting peace, and of course great rewards to come when His Kingdom is established on the new Earth! Philippians 3 v 8; Romans 8 v 18; 1 Tim 6 v 7 - 10; Matt 19 v 27, 28

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have prayed to God for a word. He specifically gave me the word CLARITY. In Mark 10:29-30 I offer the following discernment.
When Jesus speaks of in THIS AGE he is speaking of the last 1000 years of the 7000 years that makes up ALL time. Before and after there is no time, only timelessness or eternity. The hundred time reference will be fulfilled literall

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mark 10:29-30 does not mean people must give up their household to be believers of Christ. Rather, it emphasizes the importance of putting God first in our lives. In our own household, there are only a few family members. But in the household of God, there are a hundred times more. The household of God is the Church. Therefore in our own household, when other family members are Christian, in the household of God, they are family members too.

The Bible has many verses that describe the relationship of Christians as a family. For example;

> Consequently, you are no longer foreigners and strangers, but fellow **citizens with God’s people and also members of his household** (Ephesians 2:19 NIV)

> "if I am delayed, you will know how people ought to conduct themselves **in God’s household, which is the church of the living God, the pillar and foundation of the truth**". (1 Timothy 3:15 NIV)

> 1 Do not rebuke an **older man** harshly, but exhort him as if he **were your father**. Treat **younger men as brothers**, 2 **older women as mothers**, and **younger women as sisters**, with absolute purity. (1 Timothy 5:1-2 NIV)